# How do you add a JToken to an JObject?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to add a JSON object from some text to an existing JSON file using JSON.Net. For example if I have the JSON data as below:

```
  {
  "food": {
    "fruit": {
      "apple": {
        "colour": "red",
        "size": "small"
      },
      "orange": {
        "colour": "orange",
        "size": "large"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've been trying to do this like this:

```
var foodJsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var bananaJson = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""banana"" : { ""colour"": ""yellow"", ""size"": ""medium""}}");
var bananaToken = bananaJson as JToken;
foodJsonObj["food"]["fruit"]["orange"].AddAfterSelf(bananaToken);
```

But this gives the error: `"Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values."`

I've actually tried a few different ways but can't seem to get anywhere. In my example what I really want to do is add the new item to "fruit". Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this or a simpler library to use.

Answer (score 154):

I think you're getting confused about what can hold what in JSON.Net.

- A `JToken` is a generic representation of a JSON value of any kind.  It could be a string, object, array, property, etc.
- A `JProperty` is a single `JToken` value paired with a name.  It can only be added to a `JObject`, and its value cannot be another `JProperty`.
- A `JObject` is a collection of `JProperties`.  It cannot hold any other kind of `JToken` directly.

In your code, you are attempting to add a `JObject` (the one containing the "banana" data) to a `JProperty` ("orange") which already has a value (a `JObject` containing `{"colour":"orange","size":"large"}`).  As you saw, this will result in an error.

What you really want to do is add a `JProperty` called "banana" to the `JObject` which contains the other fruit `JProperties`.  Here is the revised code:

```
JObject foodJsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
JObject fruits = foodJsonObj["food"]["fruit"] as JObject;
fruits.Add("banana", JObject.Parse(@"{""colour"":""yellow"",""size"":""medium""}"));
```

Comment: Note: Use 'JToken.Parse' (or 'JToken.FromObject') instead of `JObject.Parse`, on last line. As this also works for simple objects such as string.

Comment: what to do if i want to overwrite a Jproperty.

Comment: @Daniel - If by "overwrite" you mean to completely replace the `JProperty` with a different one, then you can use the `Replace` method.  If you just want to change the value of the `JProperty`, you can set the `Value` property on it; it is writeable.  See the [LINQ-to-JSON API reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm).

Answer (score 45):

TL;DR: You should add a JProperty to a JObject. Simple. The index query returns a JValue, so figure out how to get the JProperty instead :)

---

The accepted answer is not answering the question as it seems. What if I want to specifically add a JProperty after a specific one? First, lets start with terminologies which really had my head worked up.

- JToken = The mother of all other types. It can be A JValue, JProperty, JArray, or JObject. This is to provide a modular design to the parsing mechanism.
- JValue = any Json value type (string, int, boolean).
- JProperty = any JValue or JContainer (see below) paired with a **name (identifier)**. For example `"name":"value"`.
- JContainer = The mother of all types which contain other types (JObject, JValue).
- JObject = a JContainer type that holds a collection of JProperties
- JArray = a JContainer type that holds a collection JValue or JContainer.

Now, when you query Json item using the index [], you are getting the JToken without the identifier, which might be a JContainer or a JValue (requires casting), but you cannot add anything after it, because it is only a value. You can change it itself, query more deep values, but you cannot add anything after it for example.

What you actually want to get is the property as whole, and then add another property after it as desired. For this, you use `JOjbect.Property("name")`, and then create another JProperty of your desire and then add it after this using `AddAfterSelf` method. You are done then.

For more info: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm

This is the code I modified.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      string jsonText = @"
      {
        ""food"": {
          ""fruit"": {
            ""apple"": {
              ""colour"": ""red"",
              ""size"": ""small""
            },
            ""orange"": {
              ""colour"": ""orange"",
              ""size"": ""large""
            }
          }
        }
      }";

      var foodJsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
      var bananaJson = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""banana"" : { ""colour"": ""yellow"", ""size"": ""medium""}}");

      var fruitJObject = foodJsonObj["food"]["fruit"] as JObject;
      fruitJObject.Property("orange").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("banana", fruitJObject));

      Console.WriteLine(foodJsonObj.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name + ": " + ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got your terminology wrong.  `JToken` (not `JValue`) is the base class from which `JArray`, `JObject`, `JProperty` and `JValue` ultimately inherit.  `JValue` is a JSON primitive that represents a string, number, boolean, date or null value; it cannot represent an array or object.  See the [LINQ-to-JSON API Reference](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm).

Comment: @BrianRogers Thanks, I fixed the terminology.

Comment: This is an very good explanation of the Newtonsoft object model and I am now able to understand http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm much better.  Up to now my efforts to use it have been hampered by the lack of detailed explanation in the docs.  It just seem to be an auto-generated reference from code comments.

Comment: However, code example mod is not quite right:
`
    var foodJsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
    var bananaJson = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""colour"": ""yellow"", ""size"": ""medium""}");
    var fruitJObject = foodJsonObj["food"]["fruit"] as JObject;
    fruitJObject.Property("orange").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("banana", bananaJson));
`

Comment: I can't for the life of me apply code markup to my previous comment - AARRGHH!
I've used back ticks and indented 4 spaces - how do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Just adding **`.First`** to your `bananaToken` should do it:
`foodJsonObj["food"]["fruit"]["orange"].Parent.AddAfterSelf(bananaToken` **`.First`**`);`
**`.First`** basically moves past the **`{`** to make it a **`JProperty`** instead of a **`JToken`**.

@Brian Rogers, Thanks I forgot the `.Parent`. Edited