# Adding new Jtoken to Json Jtoken

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is add a new `JToken` Under  `"message": "Login Required"` something like  `"RetryMessage": "Failed after 10 retries"`

I found this [How do you add a JToken to an JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413825/how-do-you-add-a-jtoken-to-an-jobject) which doesn't quite work I think because of the fact that error is a token and not an object but I'm not sure.

What I have tried:

```
var JsonObj = JObject.Parse(response);
var RetryMessageJson = JToken.Parse(@"{ ""RetryMessage"" : ""UnKnown""}");
JsonObj["error"]["message"].AddAfterSelf(RetryMessageJson);
```

I have tried several versions of the code above and they all come back with the following Error message:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add a JToken to an JObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413825/how-do-you-add-a-jtoken-to-an-jobject)

Comment: nope not a duplicate as that one was inserting into a JOject im inserting into a Jtoken.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unless the ordering *really* matters, I suspect you just want to make it another property of the error:

```
// Variable names edited to follow normal C# conventions
var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(response);
jsonResponse["error"]["retryMessage"] = "Unknown";
```

With your sample JSON, that results in:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required",
    "retryMessage": "Unknown"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Although Jon Skeet's answer is 100% correct, in your situation you could accomplish the same thing without explicitly specifying the exact path:

```
var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(response);
var newProperty = new JProperty("RetryMessage", "Failed after 10 retries");
jsonResponse.Last.AddAfterSelf(newProperty);
```

Comment: This sample helped me out me to figure out how to add a new property as the first property in the Json

jsonObject.AddFirst(new JProperty("Pid", 231));

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as expected when you have multiple properties. Not to say I like any of this as it feels messy.

```
var test = JToken.Parse($"{{ \"Item1\": \"Value1\", \"Item2\": \"Value2\", \"Item3\": \"Value3\" }}");
jtokenList.Add(test);
```