# Add a JObject to another JObject in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, nested, json.net

I have to create a JSON string, which should look like this at the end:

```
{
  "PersonId": "abc",
  "Firstname": "Max",
  "Lastname": "Muster",
  "AddressLine1": "Hauptstrasse 3",
  "ZipCode": "8000",
  "City": "Zürich",
  "ClubRelatedPersonDetails": 
  {
    "IsGliderInstructor": true,
    "IsGliderTrainee": false,
    "IsTowPilot": true,
  }
}
```

I already have two separate `JObjects`:

- one called `pers` which contains all the name and address info (`PersonId` through `City` in the example above)
- and another called `clubPers` which contains the club-related info (`IsGliderInstructor` through `IsTowPilot`)

So I have to add `clubPers` as a `JObject` to `pers`, I think?  How can I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413825/how-do-you-add-a-jtoken-to-an-jobject

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`Add`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm) method on the first `JObject`, providing the desired property name and the other `JObject` as parameters.

For example:

```
Dim json1 As String = _
    "{" + _
    "  ""PersonId"": ""abc""," + _
    "  ""Firstname"": ""Max""," + _
    "  ""Lastname"": ""Muster""," + _
    "  ""AddressLine1"": ""Hauptstrasse 3""," + _
    "  ""ZipCode"": ""8000""," + _
    "  ""City"": ""Zürich""" + _
    "}"

Dim json2 As String = _
    "{" + _
    "  ""IsGliderInstructor"": true," + _
    "  ""IsGliderTrainee"": false," + _
    "  ""IsTowPilot"": true" + _
    "}"

Dim pers As JObject = JObject.Parse(json1)
Dim clubPers As JObject = JObject.Parse(json2)

pers.Add("ClubRelatedPersonDetails", clubPers)

Console.WriteLine(pers.ToString())
```

Output:

```
{
  "PersonId": "abc",
  "Firstname": "Max",
  "Lastname": "Muster",
  "AddressLine1": "Hauptstrasse 3",
  "ZipCode": "8000",
  "City": "Zürich",
  "ClubRelatedPersonDetails": {
    "IsGliderInstructor": true,
    "IsGliderTrainee": false,
    "IsTowPilot": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Option Strict and Option Explicit are off:

```
Dim pers = JObject.Parse(json1)
Dim clubPers = JObject.Parse(json2)

pers.ClubRelatedPersonDetails = clubPers

Console.WriteLine(pers.ToString())
```

If they are on, then use Brian Rogers' answer.

---

Bonus: in C# we write,

```
dynamic pers = JObject.Parse(json1);
dynamic clubPers = JObject.Parse(json2);

pers.ClubRelatedPersonDetails = clubPers;
```