# Write to JArray in JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file.

```
{
  "time": [
    {
      "id": "9999",
      "name": "Foo",
      "subitem": [
        {
          "name": "Bar",
          "id": "99990",
          "visible": true,
          "subitem": [
            {
              "id": "999901",
              "name": "Flex",
              "visible": true
            },
            {
              "name": "Bear",
              "id": "999902",
              "visible": true
            },
            {
              "name": "James",
              "id": "999903",
              "visible": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Smith",
          "id": "999966",
          "visible": true
        },
        {
          "name": "John",
          "id": "999933",
          "visible": true
        }
      ],
      "visible": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Doe",
      "id": "1111",
      "visible": true,
      "subitem": [
        {
          "name": "Jack",
          "id": "111111",
          "visible": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Wilson",
          "id": "111188",
          "visible": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Andy",
          "id": "111144",
          "visible": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Gibbs",
          "id": "111155",
          "visible": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "asdf",
  "id": "13",
  "visible": true
}
```

I also have a JObject and a method to get all the JSON data and store it in this object.

```
json1 = ti.GetTimeItems();
```

I have 2 methods in another class to write to the JSON file. Where datafolder is the path.

```
public void WriteToJson(JObject obj)
{
    string fileName = dataFolder + "json1.json";
    WriteToJson(fileName, obj);
}

private void WriteToJson(string fileName, JObject obj)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(fileName))
    using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(file))
    {
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }         
}//end WriteToJson
```

Then i have a windows form where i want to take the text from 2 textboxes and add these to the JSON file.

Finally i have my click event

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string json = File.ReadAllText(url);
    //JArray time = (JArray)json1.SelectToken("time");

    json1.Add(new JObject(
    new JProperty("name", textBoxName.Text),
    new JProperty("id", textBoxId.Text),
    new JProperty("visible", true)));
    ti.WriteToJson(json1);
}
```

My problem is that i cannot seem to write to the array "time" in the JObject.
I managed to write to the file but in root instead of inside the array. 
I have tried json1.SelectToken("time") and lots of different approaches, like this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413825/how-do-you-add-a-jtoken-to-an-jobject#15782238](http://Add%20JToken%20to%20JObject) and also some approaches from the Newtonsoft documentation.

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by `((JArray)json1.GetValue("time"))`. Selecting the array in the JObject json1 and adding to that instead of the root.

Hope this will help someone.

```
  ((JArray)json1.GetValue("time")).Add(
                new JObject(
                     new JProperty("name", textBoxName.Text),
                     new JProperty("id", textBoxId.Text),
                     new JProperty("visible", true)));



            ti.WriteToJson(json1);
```