# Add a new value to a JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got the following JSON:

```
    string json = @"{
      'title': ['StarWars'],
      'description': {'StarWars': {'type': 'blog'}}
    }";
```

I want to add a new value to the description value such as:

```
string json = @"{
  'title': ['StarWars'],
  'description': {'StarWars': {'type': 'blog', 'add': true}}
}";
```

The property `StarWars` inside `description` property is always the same as the value of `title`.

How could I add the new property?

I parsed the JSON:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
object.Property("description").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("add", true));
```

And I know that's how you add a new property to a json, but I'm not sure how to add a property to a json that's encapsulated in another json.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `JObject object` is invalid declaration

Comment: Related: [How do you add a JToken to an JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15413825/10263)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to add a new token after `type`

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
jObject["description"]?["StarWars"]?["type"]?.Parent?.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("add", true));
```

`JObject` indexer returns a `JValue` of property, not the property itself, so you should access its `Parent` to call `AddAfterSelf` method.

Also, in your code `object` is invalid name for variable

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I fully understood it